# HTML Tags in Dialogflow || GCP

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-hangouts

I am trying to use HTML tags in Dialogflow Text response, the rendering in Gchats(hangout chats) isn't working

Syntax: `<b> Hello World </b>`

What i am seeing: Hello World

What i want to see : **Hello World**

TIA

Comment: Did you try the markdown style? `*bold*`

Answer (score 0):

Some other possible HTML tags for bold are:

```html
<b> Hello World </b>
<strong> Hello World </strong>
<em> Hello World </em>
```

Yet within Google Hangouts bold is accomplished with the Markdown format:

```
*Hello World*
```